# Recreating SQL statement sum (y/x)

Tags: sql, r, data.table

I want to duplicate the SQL query "select sum (x/y) from... group by ..." where first (x/y) then the result of that division is summed up by the proper grouping using the data.table package in R. My data set is 100s of millions of rows so speed is essential. My current method for the procedure is listed below in this simple toy example:

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(testkey=rep("a",3),x=1:3,y=1:3)
DT
DT[,x:=y/x]
DT
DT <- DT[,lapply(.SD,sum),by=testkey]
DT
```

Is there a faster way to accomplish this or better yet a way to do the division and summation in one step? Also, is call by reference the most computationally efficient way to do the division?

Comment: why not just `DT[, sum(x/y), by=testkey]`?

Comment: Please go through the [Introduction to data.table HTML vignette](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) (and other vignettes) if you haven't already.

Comment: @BrodieG why not just post it as answer :) one unanswered question less

Comment: @jangorecki lol, how did you even end up here!  Doing clean up on `data.table` questions?  BTW, congrats on getting involved in the project.

Comment: Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) an answer if you think it solves your problem. It will community at large to recognize the correct solution. This can be done by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. See this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) for reference. Cheers.

Comment: @BrodieG thanks, yes, keeping *answered* ratio high :)

Answer (score 4):

This should do it

```
DT[, .(x=sum(y/x)), by=testkey]
```